# For loop error in python programing

Tags: python-3.4

I typed this program exactly and it is telling me "invalid syntax"

```
print("test program for for loop")
a=int(input("enter any no")
for i in range(10):
print(a)
```

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help so that you could format your code like @pratik did

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is what you want to do..
There is syntax error in line 2. You missed closing bracket.

```
print("test program for for loop")
a = int(input("enter any no"))
for i in range (0,10):
    print(a)
```

Check if you are using python3